# Return custom page from server javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a website that has a homepage index.html and an info page.
so when someone opens www.my-website.com/info the whole page is displayed.

I want my server.js to accept links like www.my-website.com/info?=SOMETHING and then display SOMETHING on page. how do i handle such links and return page according to this?

Comment: This is way to broad for a stackoverflow question. You need to read a node.js tutorial, as they should all cover something this basic.

Comment: i'm currently just using res.sendFile() and this delivers just static pages. is there anyway i could send some data along and read it with javascript on the page @JaredSmith ??

Comment: Client-side JavaScript can parse query parameters in the URL and modify the content of the page. Unless you want to display data that only the server has, of course

Comment: @qxz thanks... worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use express to Define routes.

You need to do something like this .

Install dependencies
npm install --save express body-parser

Make your express route file.

When you define your routes, based on the parameter you need to return the name of the file .
Example:

You are calling ur.url/my-route?show=file1

```
 app.get('my-route', (req, res) => {
      var show = req.param('show');
   //based on show , you decide which file u want to send, suppose its abc.html & it is in my dist folder.        
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/abc.html'));
    });
```

Let me know if you have any issues.
you can find some nice tutorials for express like 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters